# 72 verses after morning prayer

Tags: minhag, tanach, prayer-book, shacharis-morning-prayer, nusach-ashkenaz

I've been looking at early printed prayer books, and it caught my attention that many of them contain 72 verses (שבעים ושתים פסוקים) after *Aleinu* (see this Venice edition on [p. 70](https://www.nli.org.il/he/books/NNL_ALEPH004057123/NLI) or this on [p. 84](https://www.nli.org.il/he/books/NNL_ALEPH004056511/NLI), another one from Amsterdam on [p. 64](https://www.nli.org.il/he/books/NNL_ALEPH001744499/NLI)):

> וְאַתָּ֣ה יְ֭הֹוָה מָגֵ֣ן בַּעֲדִ֑י כְּ֝בוֹדִ֗י וּמֵרִ֥ים רֹאשִֽׁי׃
> וְאַתָּ֣ה יְ֭הֹוָה אַל־תִּרְחָ֑ק אֱ֝יָלוּתִ֗י לְעֶזְרָ֥תִי חֽוּשָׁה׃
> אֹמַ֗ר לַ֭יהֹוָה מַחְסִ֣י וּמְצוּדָתִ֑י אֱ֝לֹהַ֗י אֶבְטַח־בּֽוֹ׃
> שׁוּבָ֣ה יְ֭הֹוָה חַלְּצָ֣ה נַפְשִׁ֑י ה֝וֹשִׁיעֵ֗נִי לְמַ֣עַן חַסְדֶּֽךָ׃
> דָּרַ֣שְׁתִּי אֶת־יְהֹוָ֣ה וְעָנָ֑נִי וּמִכׇּל־מְ֝גוּרוֹתַ֗י הִצִּילָֽנִי׃
> וגו'‏

What are these verses? For what purpose were they said? Are there any sources discussing this tradition?